# create-react-app does not work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

i am trying to start with a react project and i installed create-react-app with npm. 
When i do the command create-react-app pseudogram i get the following error:

```
Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
{ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\leonel\Desktop\pseudogram\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at checkNodeVersion (C:\Users\leonel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:476:23)
    at getPackageName.then.then.then.packageName (C:\Users\leonel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:283:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I tried with different versions of node and npm and still does not work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be that you didnt run `npm install`

Comment: i did run npm install

Answer (score 3):

`$ npm i -g create-react-app` . Install it globally.

After that, in your terminal, type `$ create-react-app name-of-the-app` , then `$ cd name-of-the-app` and finally `$ npm start`.

The documentation will print automatically after it finishes installing.

Comment: i installed it globally, and the create-react-app starts to run and give me this: create-react-app pseudogram

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\leonel\Desktop\pseudogram.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

C:\Users\leonel\Desktop\Projects
+-- react@16.0.0
+-- react-dom@16.0.0
`-- react-scripts@1.0.14
  `-- react-dev-utils@4.1.0
    `-- react-error-overlay@2.0.2
      +-- react@16.0.0  deduped
      `-- react-dom@16.0.0  deduped

Comment: when i first do create-react-app name-of-the-app it does not create any folder or project.     Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting pseudogram / from C:\Users\leonel\Desktop
Done.

Comment: If you are on Windows, try to run it as `PowerShell` **Admin**, if you're on Linux then try with `sudo create-react-app pseudogram `. I can't think of anything else, since the module is working properly. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: nop.. i tried everything. i open an issue with react team and they said it must be a problem with npm, a bug in their package manager.

Comment: Then try this. `npm i -g npm@4.6.1` , `npm i -g create-react-app` , `create-react-app pseudogram` , `cd pseudogram` , `npm start`. I'm out of options. But know that `create-react-app` works perfectly fine on latest version of `npm`. Or if `npm` isn't working for you, you can try to install it via `yarn`.